# Brake pedal kicks back and crunching noises when I come to a full stop

Tags: toyota, brakes, camry

So I have a 2008 Camry (v6, automatic) and this problem just started today. I was coming to a stop light and while pressing the brake it sorta kicked back at me a few times and there was a crunching noise that followed. Please help before I pay $200 for a diagnostic

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What you're describing seems to me to be the anti-lock braking system having issues. Is the brake light on? Were you on gravel or anything like that when it happened?

Answer (score 0):

Find the wheel speed sensor and tone ring at each wheel and look for an accumulation of brake dust, rust particles and/or metal filings built up on the face of the wheel speed sensor, which is magnetic.

Here is an example of these parts on a random vehicle:

[image: e]

If you find an accumulation as described (where I placed a red dot), blow it out with compressed air until the face of the wheel speed sensor is clean and free of magnetic particles.

A buildup of magnetic particles weakens the signal picked up by the tone ring, and the weakening is especially pronounced at low speeds. At low speed, the ABS module can no longer detect the rotation of one of the wheels, so it thinks the wheel has locked up due to skidding. It dutifully engages the ABS system, which is what you heard and also felt in your foot.

If you don't find a buildup, your mechanic can test the output of each wheel speed sensor with a scan tool or a scope, and replace the one with a weak signal. They do sometimes wear out and must be replaced.

If they want to replace all the wheel speed sensors without further diagnosing the issue, you might ask them to estimate the cost of a real diagnosis vs replacing parts on a hunch. It's unlikely that more than one sensor is malfunctioning. If they want to replace the ABS module on a hunch, find another shop.